# I've got this while trying to uninstall CRM module

Tags: python, module, odoo, crm

Any idea even install again or something like that erp crm error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1082, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1070, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 40, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 28, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 101, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 87, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 281, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 614, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 169, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 123, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 179, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 166, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_upgrade.py", line 90, in upgrade_module
    pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 214, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    pool.get('ir.module.module').module_uninstall(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, mod_ids_to_remove)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 441, in module_uninstall
    ir_model_data._module_data_uninstall(cr, uid, modules_to_remove, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1070, in _module_data_uninstall
    unlink_if_refcount((model, res_id) for model, res_id in to_unlink
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1059, in unlink_if_refcount
    external_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('model', '=', model),('res_id', '=', res_id)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2353, in search
    return self._search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4855, in _search
    cr.execute('SELECT "%s".id FROM ' % self._table + from_clause + where_str + order_by + limit_str + offset_str, where_clause_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 162, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 227, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Comment: how did you try to uninstall?

Comment: This question is quite underqualified. Please show all initial effort you have taken to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I am quite new so from installed modules menu. I didn't have any clue. sorry if it is novice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried using a program use as pip or brewer to install / uninstall it?
if not

```
    $ pip uninstall crm
```

Comment: doesn't work. I tried it on clean crm install and still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your server through terminal on this way

```
./openerp-server -u crm  -d DB_NAME,
```

or

```
./openerp-server -update=crm  -d DB_NAME,
```

or

```
./openerp-server -u all -d DB_NAME,
```

then try to uninstall

might be this will work for you

Comment: Thank you it was helpful but I have to do this instead:
./openerp-server -i crm -d DB_NAME,
the main problem comes from social network module I guess. Is there any check for not allowing uninstalling depending modules like social network for crm module?